# MASM32. Подскажите пожалуйста, как преобразовать число в строку, в данном случае 36. Чтобы в последующем вывести через print

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include ..\masm32\include\masm32.inc
include ..\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include ..\masm32\macros\macros.asm
includelib .\masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib .\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data
myvar db 36, 0

.code
start:
  print addr myvar
end start
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот тебе первый шаг, осилишь его подскажу дальше.

```
movzx ax, myvar
mov dx, 10
div dl
push ax

div dl
push ax

div dl
```

Comment: Первая строчка, как я понял, попытка записать в делимое ax число 36. Попробовал это сделать, masm пишет: error A2070: invalid instruction operands. Смысл третьей строки тоже не очень понятен, ясно что это деление, но кажется в делении нужно писать делитель, а какой он должен быть? Или это опечатка и имеется ввиду div dx?

Comment: Окей. Приятно видеть человека настроенного на решение своей проблемы а не на оправдание своего бессилия. Ощибка в первой строке вызвана тем что 'myvar' размером в байт а поместить ее путаються врегистр размером в слово,нужно использовать инструкцию 'movzx' которая автоматически преобразует байт в слово, заполнив все старшие биты нулями. Инструкция деления в третий строке всегда использует в качестве делимого содержание регистра RAX / EAX / AX в зависимости от размера делителя. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div

Comment: Так, с этим разобрался. Но не совсем понятно как тут участвует деление, и что с ним делать.

Comment: Целочисленное деление вернет тебе частное, то есть твое число деленное на десять в регистре AL и остаток в регистре AH, тоаким образом ты получишь первую младщую цифру твоего числа. Перенеси это число из регистра AH куда либо, к примеру в стек, и повтори это действие еще  раза, и в этоге ты получишь три числа часть которых или все могут быть тавны нулю, если твое число меньше 100 / 10 / 0

Comment: Я делю AX на 10 и получаю 3 в регистре AL и 6 в регистре AH, понятно. Например я могу поместить их в стек, достать, записав в BX. У меня получится BL 3 и BH 6, которые я уже независимо могу использовать. Но как их вывести через print?